# Present tense for future scheduled program

Tags: present-tense, will-future

I write course descriptions for an educational institution and am considering using the simple present. For e.g., "You learn how to" instead of "You will learn how to" and "We teach you what to do" instead of "We will teach you what to do"...

Is this proper? I know there's such thing as present tense for scheduled events. Is a one-day course considered a scheduled event?

Comment: It's correct to use the simple present because you teach them how to do something, or they learn something, any time they take one of the courses.  It's a habitual or repeating action that spans the present time, including both past and future occurrences.  It's like Daniel Murphy plays second base.  He might not be in a game, playing right now, but he always has, and will continue to once the new season starts.

Comment: If it is scheduled, it is a scheduled event -- so sure, a one-day course is a scheduled event.

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that the present tense usage is consistent, then such course descriptions for a one-day event would definitely make sense.